# C# String defines two File Paths

Tags: c#, visual-studio

So I have two file paths, that display two individual images that belong together. I also have a string assigned to a variable. If the string says "Tree" for example the programm needs to know the two different paths "Desktop/tree1.png" "[...]tree2.png" for example. How can I do this efficiently, as I have around 50ish strings and their two paths. I think If-statements might not be the most efficient way. Any ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, it seems that the following would do the trick:

```
string path1 = $"Desktop/{fileName}1.png";
string path2 = $"Desktop/{fileName}2.png";
```

Answer (score 0):

you better seperate paths with one character and when use paths split on seperate character like this sample :

```
string yourPaths="path1,path2,path3,....";
string[] paths=yourPaths.split[','];
string path1=paths[0];
string path2=paths[1];
...
```

and use paths in your code

for seach in your paths you can use foreach

```
foreach(var path in paths){
if(desiredPath==path){} //desiredPath is your desired Path for search
else{}
}
```

and if you want conbine 2 or more path to together you can use StringBuilder

```
 StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    builder.Append(path1);
    builder.Append(path2); //path1+path2
```

Comment: Can you explain the foreach search a bit more? Im sorry for being a noob

Comment: for example you want find one path in paths,foreach search in all path step by step ,you just set if for desiredPath and foreach compare your desiredpath with all paths